# How to maintain view hierarchy in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Say I have 3 view controllers: VC1, VC2 ,VC3. 
The normal flow would be that VC1 segues to VC2 and VC2 segues to VC3. The user has the option to unwind to VC2 from VC3. However, in one specific instance VC1 pushes to VC3. In this case the unwind segue to VC2 doesn't work. I would assume because VC2 never gets added to the stack of VCs. What other alternatives are there to perform the following: VC1->VC3->VC2. Is there anyway to add all view controllers in the chain to the stack when pushing to a view controller further down the chain?
Thanks

Comment: Use can use `unwind segue` from VC3 to VC1 directly. Write the method in VC1 (similar as you wrote in VC2), and connect exit outlet from VC3

Comment: I need to go from VC3 to VC2 though after going from VC1 to VC3 directly

Comment: You can perform the segues programmatically too. When unwind segue(VC3 to VC1) occurs, then you can perform the another segue(VC2 to VC3).

Answer (score 0):

I've used below approach on my app and it works fine.

`vc2.navigationController.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
    vc1.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)`

Comment: I've tried something similar now that seems works. I just push all the necessary VCs onto the stack. I don't know if this is the most efficient solution though